# How I can get coverage for cargo test?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, code-coverage, rust-cargo, kcov

When I want to test C++ coverage, I can build my program with `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`, run all tests, and run `gcov` to get coverages.

However, when it comes to Rust, I get totally lost. What I want to do is run the following tests(on my Mac), and get coverage of all Rust codes in path `components/raftstore`

```
cargo test --package tests --test failpoints cases::test_normal
cargo test --package tests --test failpoints cases::test_bootstrap
cargo test --package tests --test failpoints cases::test_compact_log
```

From [this post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/tutorial-how-to-collect-test-coverages-for-rust-project/650), it says firstly run `cargo test --no-run`, then run `kcov`. However, when I actually do that, kcov blocks forever.

Then I [find something called](https://github.com/kennytm/cargo-kcov) `cargo kcov`, who provides `--test`. However when I run `cargo kcov --test failpoints cases::test_normal` like what I do in `cargo test`, I get error

```
error: cargo subcommand failure
note: cargo test exited with code exit status: 101
error: no test target named `failpoints`
```

I have tried many ways to figure this out, however, none of them works, so I wonder if I can get some help here.

I know there are other coverage tools like `tarpaulin` and `grcov`, I am currently trying those. It is also acceptable if there are neat solutions with those coverage tools. **However**, I still want to know what is wrong with `kcov` and `cargo-kcov`.

Comment: @mori The link appears to be dead

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Astariul. Please refer to the answer below which I've just posted. It also contains the link the corresponding section in the rustc book.

Answer (score 10):

I like to use [tarpaulin](https://github.com/xd009642/tarpaulin) with the HTML output.

```bash
cargo tarpaulin --out Html
```

This should create an output file named `tarpaulin-report.html`. Open this file in the browser to view the code coverage report.

Answer (score 4):

According to [rustc docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/instrument-coverage.html#test-coverage), it's now possible to obtain instrumentation-based code coverage.

The following command generates coverage results. Note that it requires
the Rust profiler runtime, which is included by default in `nightly`.

```
RUSTFLAGS="-C instrument-coverage" \
    cargo test --tests
```

These results may include mangled symbol names, which can be worked around with [rustfilt](https://crates.io/crates/rustfilt):

```
cargo install rustfilt
```

After running tests with this setup there should be one or more `.profraw` files. If there are multiple, they can be merged with:

```
$ llvm-profdata merge -sparse default_*.profraw -o your_crate.profdata
```

Coverage information can then be shown with [llvm-cov](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-cov.html), for instance like described in [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/instrument-coverage.html#test-coverage) (substitute the names of your crate and test binaries).

There might be issues if the LLVM versions of rustc and llvm-profdata resp. llvm-cov don't match, as noted [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/instrument-coverage.html#installing-llvm-coverage-tools).

This answer is based on [this section of the rustc book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/instrument-coverage.html#instrumentation-based-code-coverage), which offers much more information on code coverage.

Answer (score 2):

The answers [from Mori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74316930/4893482) and [from Saurabh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76139111/4893482) describe in some detail how to configure rustc to provide [instrumentation-based code coverage](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/instrument-coverage.html#creating-coverage-reports).

It is now possible to benefit from instrumentation-based coverage much more simply. [cargo-llvm-cov](https://github.com/taiki-e/cargo-llvm-cov) can do this in a single command:

```
cargo llvm-cov
```

*Note that as of `0.5.37`, it does not have branch coverage (see https://github.com/taiki-e/cargo-llvm-cov/issues/8) or stable support for doc tests (see https://github.com/taiki-e/cargo-llvm-cov/issues/2).*

Likewise, tarpaulin mentioned in [the answer from Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75792344/4893482) has been updated to use rustc's llvm instrumentation.  By default, this is only used on macOS and Windows.  On Linux it can be enabled with

```
cargo tarpaulin --engine llvm
```

Comment: `llvm-cov` proved to be a perfect alternative in my case since I needed to manipulate env vars within my tests and for some reason `tarpaulin` got issues handling tests that had otherwise no issue via a regular `cargo test` (even without parallelization). It's also way faster. For future reference: https://github.com/ivangabriele/mistralai-client-rs/commits/main/?since=2024-03-05&until=2024-03-05.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate source-based coverage for your project by:

- Enable coverage profile in `Cargo.toml`:

  ```ini
  ...
  [build]
  profiler = true
  ...
  ```
- Install demangler

  ```
  cargo install rustfilt
  ```
- Add instrument coverage

  ```
  export RUSTFLAGS="-C instrument-coverage=all"
  ```
- Install dependencies `openssl-devel`, `libssl-devel`, `llvm`, and `genhtml`, based on your OS
- Install [Mozilla's grcov](https://github.com/mozilla/grcov) and link the profiler with the rust compiler

  ```
  cargo install grcov
  rustup component add llvm-tools-preview
  ```
- Run tests

  ```
  cargo test --verbose
  ```
- Generate code coverage information

  ```
  grcov . -s . --binary-path ./target/debug/ -t lcov --branch --ignore-not-existing -o ./target/debug/
  ```
- Create HTML report from coverage data

  ```
  genhtml -o ./target/debug/coverage/ --show-details --highlight --ignore-errors source --legend ./target/debug/lcov
  ```

And finally view the HTML report at `./target/debug/coverage/index.html`

Comment: Damn 8 steps. I'm guessing this is not the simplest approach.